# Is it properly quoted when I using '*' or '**/*' in bash?

Tags: bash, escaping, glob

`find -name '*.jpg' -print0 | xargs -0 qiv`

`qiv **/*.jpg`

both are safely escaped and delivered to `qiv`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In the first case, `find` is expanding the wildcard internally, and delivering results to `xargs` as it expects them. In the second, the shell is expanding them and passing each match as a separate argument. Both are correct (assuming shell support for `**`, and that the command line length maximum isn't exceeded).